# TypeScript: TS2036 "not a module" error when working with DefinitelyTyped definitions

Tags: typescript, amd, typescript-typings

I've pulled the `react.d.ts` file from [DefinitelyTyped](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/master/react/react.d.ts), and included it in my project as `node_modules/react/react.d.ts`. Now, when I write `import * as React from "node_modules/react/react"`, I get the following error:

```
Error TS2306: File '.../node_modules/react/react.d.ts' is not a module.
```

I can work around this by changing the following lines in `react.d.ts`:

```
declare module "react" {
    export = __React;
}
```

to:

```
export = __React;
```

My question is: what's the suggested workflow for working with TypeScript definition files?

Comment: Why are you explicitly giving the filepath within node modules? You should only need `import * as React from "react"`

Comment: Then how does RequireJS know where to find my modules?

Comment: You tell it the paths in `require.config({paths: {...}})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new TypeScript 2.0, still in beta (`npm install typescript@beta -g`), you should grab your definition files with `npm install @types/react`.
Secondly, if there is a statement `export =` in a module (or a declaration of a module), you should import accordingly with syntax `import =` like the following: `import React = require('react');`